# Not working SaveChanges() method ASP.NET MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

My code runs without error message, but the data not saved in the database. What can I do to make it save the data?

After running method `SavePictureToDatabase` Visual Studio show this information:

[image]

My model:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;

namespace userGallery.Models
{
    public class Image
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public int AccountId { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
    }
}
```

ModelContext:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Data.Entity;

namespace userGallery.Models
{
    public class ImageContext : DbContext
    {
        public DbSet<Image> Images { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Controller:

```
public class UserController : Controller
    {
        ImageContext context = new ImageContext();

        // GET: User
        public ActionResult Download()
        {
            return View();
        }

        public string SavePictureToDatabase()
        {    
            Image image = new Image()
            {
                AccountId = 1,
                Name = "123",
            };

            context.Images.Add(image);
            context.SaveChanges();

            return urlPicture;
        }
```

Connection string:

```
<connectionStrings>
    <add name="DefaultConnection" connectionString="Data Source=(LocalDb)\MSSQLLocalDB;AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|\aspnet-userGallery-20160714070926.mdf;Initial Catalog=aspnet-userGallery-20160714070926;Integrated Security=True" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
  </connectionStrings>
```

Structure of the database:

[image]

Comment: do you any connection string?

Comment: connection string added post

Comment: and write the exception stack trace please.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pass connectionString to DbContext, when DbContext class name and ConnectionString not equal

```
public class ImageContext : DbContext
{
    public ImageContext (): base("DefaultConnection")
    {
    }

    public DbSet<Image> Images { get; set; }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

have you got any exceptions?

if you see the exceptions, you should write the code below.

```
try 
{
    Context.Content.Add(content);
    Context.SaveChanges();
}
catch (DbEntityValidationException e) 
{
    foreach(var eve in e.EntityValidationErrors) 
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Entity  \"{0}\" exceptions \"{1}\" :", eve.Entry.Entity.GetType().Name, eve.Entry.State);
        foreach(var ve in eve.ValidationErrors) 
        {
            Console.WriteLine("- Property: \"{0}\", Error: \"{1}\"", ve.PropertyName, ve.ErrorMessage);
        }
    }
}
```